# Hibernate SQL Exception

Tags: java, hibernate, sqlexception

From the past few days i am getting this strange exception in ApacheTomcat logs when i run the Java struts2 webapplication in netbeans IDE. I couldn't figure out which part of the code is causing this exception.

```
May 5, 2012 12:16:47 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/latest-raisin]   
threw exception [org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not execute JDBC 
batch update] with root cause
java.sql.SQLException: Data truncated for column 'synsettype' at row 1
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3603)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3535)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1989)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2150)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2626)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2119)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2415)
at 
com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:1976)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatch(PreparedStatement.java:1449)
at 

com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeBatch(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:1723)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:114)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:109)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareBatchStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:244)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2541)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2494)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2821)
at org.hibernate.action.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:113)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:273)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:265)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:185)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:383)
at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:133)
at com.generalsentiment.management.filters.PersistenceSessionFilter.doFilter(PersistenceSessionFilter.java:48)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at com.generalsentiment.management.filters.DisableUrlSessionFilter.doFilter(DisableUrlSessionFilter.java:91)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:964)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Info - synsettype is actually a column in the Synset table.

Answer (score 5):

I'd guess the data you try to insert is too long for the column. Try to increase the size of the column

Comment: The synsettype column is of varchar(200) and the value it can have is either   "REGULAR"    or  "BOOLEAN" ..  no other value as per the business rules..

Comment: use showSql=true to display the actual insert statement, and also debug the values to see if there isn't another value, or unnecessary whitespaces

Comment: @Sangram Anand:) `java.sql.SQLException: Data truncated for column 'synsettype' at row 1`. Obviously, data truncation occurs.